# Convert string to datetime - python dataframe

Tags: python, datetime

Hi I want to convert a dataframe column (string) into date.I found it converted some of the dates correctly and some of them are wrong.

```
df
  Id       Date     Rev
1605380 1/12/2018   3000.0
2237851 27/11/2018  3000.0
1797180 11/2/2018   2000.0
1156126 9/1/2018    2000.0
1205792 8/4/2017    2000.0
```

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

The output I got

```
 Id       Date      Rev
1605380 2018-01-12  3000.0
2237851 2018-11-27  3000.0
1797180 2018-11-02  2000.0
1156126 2018-09-01  2000.0
1205792 2017-08-04  2000.0
```

It seems that if the "day" is not two digit, datetime converted it into "month" instead of "day". Therefore, 1/12/2018 should be 2018-12-01, not 2018-01-12. 
How can I fix this issue ?

I actually only need year and month for the output.

Ideal output

```
  Id       Date     Rev
1605380 2018-12    3000.0
2237851 2018-11    3000.0
1797180 2018-02    2000.0
1156126 2018-01    2000.0
1205792 2017-04    2000.0
```

Comment: You can use `format` in the `to_datetime` function to encode the exact syntax of the date you have: here it would be `format="%d/%m/%Y"` after that you can convert the datetime object to any string, cf. here  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html.

Comment: Note that `pandas` is trying to be helpful and interpret your date and time strings as `m/d/Y`, except in cases where it can't and where it tries alternatives like `d/m/Y` (as it did for `27/11/2018`). @Ascurion's suggestion is the correct way forwards, as it should always be '%m/%d/%Y' in your case, it appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the `format` parameter to `'%d/%m/%Y'` to explicitly tell the date format as commented. Or set `dayfirst` to `True`. A datetime object actually has information for year, month, day, and time, so to get just month and year displayed, you'll have to convert back to string:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. It still extracts "day" as month, instead of "month" for day that are not two digits. for example 1/12/2018 becomes 2018-01, however it should be 2018-12

Comment: That's odd. Works for me. Is that the case for both `dayfirst=True` and `format='%d/%m/%Y`?